# More efficient python for loop (3 redundant loops) at large values of iterations

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, largenumber

I'm trying to implement the following code:

```
def foo(n, p):
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1,n):
            for k in range(1,n):
                if ((n-j)*i*k)==(j*(n-i)*(n-k)):
                    p=p-11
```

But n is going to be approaching values of 10^10, making this grossly inefficient. In fact, this is slow even when n=1000.

Is there a way to speed this up by condensing the for loops, or perhaps a way to do this without for loops at all?

Comment: And what is this code suppose to accomplish?

Comment: it's an implementation of the inner loop of: https://oeis.org/A092098 (and somehow three intersections are supposed to create 11 instead of 6 regions as per the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a math approach vs. a computer science approach. There are obviously interesting issues with reducing those for loops, but the math approach might get you pretty much the same thing with a tiny error.

I was wondering if there was a closed-form formula for this sequence, as that's always going to be faster than any loops! In the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A092098) link you provided, under FORMULA, someone provided an "empirical" generating function of

```
x*(1+5*x+11*x^2+x^3+6*x^4)/(1-x)^3/(1+x)^2
```

I'll get to the "empirical" part in a bit. But because this is a ratio of polynomials, it is fairly easy to get a closed-form solution if you read about how generating functions work. I can add the algebra to my answer if this approach ends up being something you like, but for now, let's just cut straight to the formula:

```
def empirical(n):
    return ((-1)**n * (-1.5*n + 2.5)) + \
               (3.0*n**2 - 4.5*n + 3.5)
```

It's very clean and simple. How accurate is this? Well, I checked for the first 500 values. The two functions usually line up perfectly, but there are occasional times when `empirical` overstates the true sequence:

```
    correct  empirical  pct_diff
1         1        1.0  0.000000
2         6        6.0  0.000000
3        19       19.0  0.000000
4        30       30.0  0.000000
5        61       61.0  0.000000
6        78       78.0  0.000000
7       127      127.0  0.000000
8       150      150.0  0.000000
9       217      217.0  0.000000
10      246      246.0  0.000000
11      331      331.0  0.000000
12      366      366.0  0.000000
13      469      469.0  0.000000
14      510      510.0  0.000000
15      625      631.0  0.009600*
16      678      678.0  0.000000
17      817      817.0  0.000000
18      870      870.0  0.000000
19     1027     1027.0  0.000000
20     1080     1086.0  0.005556*
21     1261     1261.0  0.000000
22     1326     1326.0  0.000000
```

That occasional difference is almost always less than 1%. Now, I can't guarantee that this pattern is going to hold for `n = 10**10` (i.e., where empirical is almost always right, with slight overstatements every so often), but check out another comment on the OEIS page:

> Ceva's Theorem is used to deduct vanishing regions from the naive count. The first deduction is at n=15 for n odd and n=20 for n even.

15 and 20 happen to be the first disagreements with `empirical`! So it seems like the empirical generating function is correct most of the time (the "naive count"?), but it's an upper bound in some spots when a deduction has to be made. That's getting into domain-specific territory, and I don't know enough about Ceva's Theorem to see exactly when and how to make those deductions—so I'm afraid I can't improve on this closed-form upper bound as I have it above.

Your original question wanted to test 10**10. So now do `int(empirical(10**10))` instantly:

```
299999999939999956992
```

This is either exactly correct, or an upper bound that's very, very close to the real answer.

I know this is a bit of an "alternative" solution, but hopefully it's an informative diversion. It's like when someone asks you to find the (10**10)th Fibonacci number. You can do loops, but if a closed-form formula exists, use it!

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating `(n-j)*i*k=j*(n-i)*(n-k)`. We have that `j=n/(((n-i)*(n-k))/(i*k) + 1)` and j should be an integer between 1 and n-1, so:

```
def foo(n, p):
    for i in range(1,n):
        for k in range(1,n):
            j=n/(((n-i)*(n-k))/(i*k) + 1)
            if n%(((n-i)*(n-k))/(i*k) + 1) == 0 and j > 0 and j < n:
                p=p-11
```

This reduces the complexity from O(n³) to O(n²)

Comment: this works well for n=1000, but I haven't been able to get it to return for n=10^10; is there any way I could extrapolate n=10^10 from smaller numbers or reduce the for loop even further?